# Get rid of time in CSV file (Python)

Tags: python, datetime

This is my huge csv file. 

`"2017/03/04 14:49:15", "a"
"2017/03/04 14:49:16", "b"
"2017/03/04 14:50:32", "c"`

What is the way in python to get the below output?

#### wanted ouput 1: only show hour

`"2017/03/04 14", "a"
"2017/03/04 14", "b"
"2017/03/04 14", "c"`

#### wanted output 2: only show date

`"2017/03/04", "a"
"2017/03/04", "b"
"2017/03/04", "c"`

Comment: I suggest you try writing some code.  Use the built in `csv` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to read each entry in as a datatime object and then format it as required using the [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y/%d/%m %H")
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

For the hour output:

```
"2017/03/04 14","a"
"2017/03/04 14","b"
"2017/03/04 14","c"
```

---

To then modify it to remove the hour, just change the `strftime()` as required, e.g.

```
row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y/%d/%m")
```

It uses `strptime()` to first convert the string into a datatime object. It is then passed to `strftime()` to convert it back into a differently formatted string.

Python's `csv` library takes care of splitting all the elements in each row of the file into a list format.